# How do I fix pagination in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I am using pagination in Codeigniter where I have 4 records in my table and I want to show each record on each page. I am able to get the first record on page load but when i clicked to page no.2 it gives me data of page no.3 How can I fix it?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z83D7.jpg)

Here is my code

```
$config = [];
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "news/page/";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->newsmodel->getNewsCount();
        $config["per_page"] = 1;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config["use_page_numbers"] = true;
        $config["page_query_string"] = false;
        $config["first_tag_open"] = '<li class="page-item">';
        $config["first_tag_close"] = "</li>";
        $config["prev_tag_open"] = '<li class="page-item">';
        $config["prev_tag_close"] = "</li>";
        $config["num_tag_open"] = '<li class="page-item">';
        $config["num_tag_close"] = "</li>";
        $config["prev_link"] = '<i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>';
        $config["next_link"] = '<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>';
        $config["cur_tag_open"] =
            '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link active">';
        $config["cur_tag_close"] = "</a></li>";
        $config["next_tag_open"] = '<li class="page-item">';
        $config["next_tag_close"] = "</li>";
        $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = round($choice);
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        if($this->uri->segment(3)) {
            $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
        } else {
            $page = 0;
        }
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        if ($data["links"] != "") {
            $data["pagermessage"] =
                "Showing " .
                (($this->pagination->cur_page - 1) *
                    $this->pagination->per_page +
                    1) .
                " to " .
                $this->pagination->cur_page * $this->pagination->per_page .
                " of " .
                $config["total_rows"];
        }
        $data["newsDetails"] = $this->newsmodel->newsList($config["per_page"], $page);
        $this->load->view("news_details", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

why you are going into complex programming situation. The best and easy solution is here. Please follow this code.

Assuming we have a users table in which 100 number of rows. Now, we will show users data into view with pagination links.

Open any controller, say **SiteController.php** and write this complete code into it.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use App\Models\UserModel;

class SiteController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = new UserModel;

        $paginateData = $users->paginate(5);

        $data = [
            'users' => $paginateData,
            'pager' => $users->pager,
            'search' => $search
        ];

        return view('users', $data);
    }
}
```

By above code, we are sending users data into users view.

```php
<table class="table table-hover" style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach ($users as $dt) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $dt['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $dt['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $dt['email'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- Paginate -->
<div style='margin-top: 10px;'>
    <?= $pager->links() ?>
</div>
```

I hope it will help you.